# Validating IPv6 checked or unchecked in Network Adapter Properties

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

My Requirement is to uncheck `IPv6` if it is checked or if unchecked then display already unchecked.

I tried below code but it's not giving any output nor any error.

```
 
$IPv6 = Get-NetAdapterBinding | Select-Object Name, DisplayName, ComponentID, Enabled | where { $_.Name -match 'Ethernet' -and $_.ComponentID -match 'ms_tcpip6' -and $_.Enabled -match 'False' }
If ($IPv6)
{
If ($IPv6.Name -match 'Wi-Fi' -and $IPv6.ComponentID -match 'ms_tcpip6' -and $IPv6.Enabled -match 'False')
{Write-Host 'IPv6 Already disabled for Ethernet & Wi-Fi Adapter' -ForegroundColor DarkYellow} 
}else
{
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name * -DisplayName "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)"
Write-Host 'IPv6 disabled for Ethernet & Wi-Fi Adapter' -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PowerShell will display enabled network adapters with IPv6 enabled. It will disable IPv6 on the adapters which it is enabled, and then show you the adapters with it disabled (*before & after*).

Adding additional conditional logic to narrow down specifics is a trivial matter, but this is the code to use for all adapters that are enabled that will assist you in accomplishing your final goal.

### PowerShell

```
$N = Get-NetAdapterBinding | Select-Object Name, DisplayName, ComponentID, Enabled;

Write-Host "Before disabling IPv6 where enabled" -ForegroundColor Magenta;
$N | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.ComponentID -match 'ms_tcpip6' -and $_.Enabled -match 'False' ) { Write-Host "$($_.Name) ==> IPv6 Disabled" -ForegroundColor Yellow; };
    If ($_.ComponentID -match 'ms_tcpip6' -and $_.Enabled -match 'True' ) { 
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) ==> IPv6 Enabled" -ForegroundColor Green; 
        Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "$($_.Name)" -ComponentID 'ms_tcpip6';};
    };

$N = Get-NetAdapterBinding | Select-Object Name, DisplayName, ComponentID, Enabled;

Write-Host "";
Write-Host "After disabling IPv6 where enabled" -ForegroundColor Magenta;

$N | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.ComponentID -match 'ms_tcpip6' -and $_.Enabled -match 'False' ) { Write-Host "$($_.Name) ==> IPv6 Disabled" -ForegroundColor Yellow; };
    If ($_.ComponentID -match 'ms_tcpip6' -and $_.Enabled -match 'True' ) { 
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) ==> IPv6 Enabled" -ForegroundColor Green;
        };
    };
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-NetAdapterBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapterbinding?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
- [Disable-NetAdapterBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/disable-netadapterbinding?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)
- [Write-Host](https://ss64.com/ps/write-host.html)
- [PowerShell Operators $( ) @( ) :: &](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)